# LINQ - Select all children from an object hierarchy

Tags: c#, linq

I have a `List` of objects which contain a string array as one of their properties. I want to get a distinct string array containing all the values.

My object looks like this:

```
public class Zoo {
    string Name { get; set;}
    string[] Animals { get; set;}
}
```

Some zoos may have only one animal, some may have many. What would be the simplest Lambda expression or LINQ query to get me a unique list of all animals at all the Zoos in `List<Zoo>`?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
var query = zoos.SelectMany(zoo => zoo.Animals)
                .Distinct();
```

Or if you're a query expression fan (I wouldn't be for something this simple):

```
var query = (from zoo in zoos
             from animal in zoo.Animals
             select animal).Distinct();
```

Comment: Where was the typo? I must have missed it :)

Comment: The typo was in my application. I can't wait until the StackOverflow addin for Visual Studio comes out so you can fix my apps as I work. :-)