# Generic LINQ function - SelectMany with selection Func as a parameter

Tags: c#, linq-to-objects

I've got a class with many string arrays. I'd like to have one generic function which can get me a unique `List<string>` for a given property. Example:

```
public class Zoo 
{    
  string Name { get; set;}
  string[] Animals { get; set;}
  string[] Zookeepers { get; set;}
  string[] Vendors { get; set;}
}
```

I'd like to have a generic function that will get me a distinct `List<string>` of Animals in List? I want this to be generic, so I can also get a distinct list of Zookeepers and Vendors.

I've been trying this, but it doesn't compile:

```
public static List<string> GetExtendedList(Func<Zoo, string[]> filter)
{
        var Zoos = QueryZoos(HttpContext.Current);
        return Zoos.Where(z => z.Type == "Active")
            .SelectMany(filter)
            .Distinct()
            .OrderBy(s => s);
    }
```

Note: this is related to two questions I've asked before, but I'm having trouble merging the information. I previously asked [how to query using SelectMany (SO 1229897)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1229897/linq-select-all-children-from-an-object-hierarchy) and separately asked how to write a generic function which [gets a list using Select rather than SelectMany (SO 1278989)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1278989/how-can-i-set-linq-selectmany-projection-via-func-parameter).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

> "Each Zoo"

*click*

Suppose you had a list of zoo's:

```
List<Zoo> zooList = GetZooList();
```

Then, if you wanted distinct animals from all the zoos, you would apply SelectMany in this way:

```
List<string> animalList = zooList
  .SelectMany(zoo => zoo.animals)
  .Distinct()
  .ToList();
```

And If you commonly did this task and wanted one function to wrap these three calls, you could write such a function this way:

```
public static List<string> GetDistinctStringList<T>(
  this IEnumerable<T> source,
  Func<T, IEnumerable<string>> childCollectionFunc
)
{
  return source.SelectMany(childCollectionFunc).Distinct().ToList();
}
```

Which would then be called:

```
List<string> animals = ZooList.GetDistinctStringList(zoo => zoo.animals);
```

And for the code sample that doesn't compile (for which you've given no error message), I deduce you need to add a ToList():

```
.OrderBy(s => s).ToList();
```

The other problem (why the type argument can't be inferred) is that `string[]` doesn't implement `IEnumerable<string>`.  Change that type parameter to `IEnumerable<string>` instead of `string[]`

Comment: My error message: 
Error 15 The type arguments for method 'System.Linq.Enumerable.SelectMany<TSource,TResult>(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TSource>, System.Func<TSource,System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TResult>>)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.

Comment: Thanks, this worked great. I'm going to accept and will look at converting it to a non-extension method just to make sure I fully understand it. The main problem I had seems to be in declaring the Func param correctly.

Comment: Actually, `string[]` does implement `IEnumerable<string>`. The real problem is that `Func<Zoo, string[]>` is a delegate type that is different from `Func<Zoo, IEnumerable<string>>`; and different delegate types are not directly compatible.

Answer (score 1):

The best way would be to create a [`HashSet<String>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438.aspx) for each `String[]` - this would filter out all duplicates.

Since `HashSet<T>` has a constructor that accepts an `IEnumerable<T>` you could simply instantiate a `HashSet<T>` by passing each of your arrays into the constructor.  The resulting `HashSet<T>` would be the distinct list of `Strings`.  While this is not a `List<String>` like you requested, `HashSet<T>` *does* implement `ICollection<T>` so many of the methods you would need may be available.

```
static ICollection<String> GetDistinct(IEnumerable<String> sequence)
{
    return new HashSet<String>(sequence);
}
```

Comment: I don't need to filter duplicates in each list, I need a de-duped list of child items across all items in the collection. To keep with my analogy, it's fine if each Zoo has a Lion and a Tiger, but I need a function which will get me a list of all Animal types in all my Zoos.

Comment: Hmm.. I see what you mean.  Is refactoring the `Zoo` type an option?

Comment: It could be, but I'd really like to learn the LINQ solution rather than just restating the problem every time I hit this. Appreciate the input, though!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I am missing what you mean, but simply...

```
List<String> distinctAnimals = zoo.Animals.Distinct().ToList();
```

will do what you are asking, I assume you mean something else?

Edit:
If you have a list of Zoos but want the distinct animals then select many is the correct thing to use, IMO its easier using the linq declarative syntax...

```
List<String> animals = (from z in zoos
                       from s in z.Animals
                       select s).Distinct().ToList();
```

Comment: He's asking for a generic solution, not that Distinct().ToList() aren't generic, take a look at his other posts.

Comment: Sorry, my question wasn't clearly stated. I'm looking for a generic solution. I've updated the question statement.

Comment: Ah I see what you mean now after the Edit. I think that Andrew has the correct answer.